# How wise it is to use a servlet for a login form?

Tags: forms, servlets, authentication

I'm developing some web service using Resin and at the beginning I was using a servlet to log users but I quit and decided to user a class provided by resin called AbstractAuthenticator. At the end I feel although it was easier it ended up being the same since there's no encryption and now the user and password are naked in the URL. So my question is how common it is to user servlet for a login form? What is the most common approach to this? I know I will end up using SSL since using a digest authentication provided by the browser window is very obtrusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That it's a servlet isn't why the username/password are in the URL, that's because it's a GET request and not a POST.

Login forms can be handled by any number of back-end technologies, while a great many people use a framework, there's no technical reason it *can't* be handled by a servlet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I know servlets using POST don't have that problem, I didn't in the beginning but now that I'm using Resin's AbstractAuthenticator vlass (which uses GET I guess) I'm having that issue. I think there is a way to fix in the custom Resin's xml tags but all this made me rethink about using a servlet vs AbstractAuthenticator.

Comment: What is the most common Java based login framework, or the best in your opinion?

Comment: @Jigzat There's no "best", only "most appropriate". Don't over-think it: if it's secure, and it works, what's the issue?

Comment: thanks for your time Dave. I think I have a lot in my mind and I want to be sure to take the right choices since right now I am doing all by myself.